# If string detected in df, create new column with replacement string + R + dplyr

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, mutate

I'm using the mutate method to find strings in a column (`Name` in the example)and replace them with a corrected string in R, which works well both on partial and full strings.

Method:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally","Jimmm","Boob","Suezi","Sallyyyy","Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally"),
Period = c("P1","P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2","P2","P3","P3","P3","P3"),
Value = c(150, 200, 325, 120, 760,245,46,244,200, 325, 120, 760))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Name = case_when(
  str_detect(Name, "Jim") ~ "Jim",
str_detect(Name, "Sue") ~ "Sue",
  TRUE ~ Name)) %>%
  mutate(across(Name, str_replace, "Sallyyyy", "Sally"))
```

In my real application I realized I should probably maintain the original column for reference and and create a new column with the corrections.

I tried simply adding a new column the standard way in r, as below:

```
df$test <- df %>% 
  mutate(Name = case_when(
  str_detect(Name, "Jim") ~ "Jim",
  TRUE ~ Name)) %>%
  mutate(across(Name, str_replace, "Sallyyyy", "Sally"))
```

but instead of just creating a new column called `test`, in this case it creates a copy of the entire dataframe.

Is there a method within the mutate function that will allow me to create a new column with the correction as opposed to replacing it in the original column?

Comment: It seems that you are intending to apply this correction logic to multiple columns (not just `Name`), how do you intend to store the results of multiple columns? Perhaps if your sample data included multiple columns requiring fixing, and you provided a clear example of your expected output (as another `data.frame`), it would help understand. Thanks.

Comment: No, I just want to apply it to one column as in the example, and create a new column with the results. As opposed to replacing the strings in the existing column. For example, each time the word `Jim` is detected in a row a corresponding row in a new column will be created containing `Jim`

Comment: Why mention *"~100 columns so not at all efficient"* if you're only intending to work on one column?

Comment: Because in the method I tried, `df$test <- ...` to create a new column containing the answer it actually creates a replica of the entire df. Which may seem reasonable in a 1d array suchs as the example but is not efficent when you have a large df with multiple columns. ~100 in this case...

Comment: The output from `... %>% mutate(across(...))` is the original frame, columns and all. You then assign that whole frame back to a column of the original frame, which makes that a list-column (and unlikely to be what is truly needed). Since you are only operating on a single column, it seems best to just do `... %>% mutate(test = case_when(...))` instead, far simpler, easier to read.

Comment: I've taken that line out to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm out, JohnConor, good luck.

Comment: Apologies, that was probably a little harsh. I just didn't find the solution very easy to follow. I was in the process of offering to change it but understand your frustration. I appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I'm over complicating this, the simple solution here is to just create a copy of the column and apply the correction to the copied column, like so:

```
df$Name_Correct <- df$Name
```

Full solution:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally","Jimmm","Boob","Suezi","Sallyyyy","Jim","Bob","Sue","Sally"),
                 Period = c("P1","P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2","P2","P3","P3","P3","P3"),
                 Value = c(150, 200, 325, 120, 760,245,46,244,200, 325, 120, 760))

df$Name_Correct <- df$Name

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Name_Correct = case_when(
    str_detect(Name_Correct, "Jim") ~ "Jim",
    str_detect(Name_Correct, "Sue") ~ "Sue",
    TRUE ~ Name_Correct)) %>%
  mutate(across(Name_Correct, str_replace, "Sallyyyy", "Sally"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe full of good names, you could try to partially match the closest name. You could use the built in `babynames` dataset for reference. This way, you would need no `case_when` and you could recode all in one go:

```r
library(tidyverse)

nms <- babynames::babynames |>
  filter(year > 1990) |>
  filter(!duplicated(name)) |>
  pull(name)

df |>
  mutate(Name_Correct = map_chr(Name, ~nms[which.min(stringdist::stringdist(.x, nms ))]))
#>        Name Period Value Name_Correct
#> 1       Jim     P1   150          Jim
#> 2       Bob     P1   200          Bob
#> 3       Sue     P1   325          Sue
#> 4     Sally     P1   120        Sally
#> 5     Jimmm     P2   760        Jimmy
#> 6      Boob     P2   245          Bob
#> 7     Suezi     P2    46         Suzi
#> 8  Sallyyyy     P2   244        Sally
#> 9       Jim     P3   200          Jim
#> 10      Bob     P3   325          Bob
#> 11      Sue     P3   120          Sue
#> 12    Sally     P3   760        Sally
```

Its not perfect, but you can refine with the `stringdist` function to get it tuned up correctly.